# iPhone duplicate symbol error

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, mobfox

I have iPhone App and i want to include `MobFox` ads in it, after i add their Framework i got this error:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDataScanner in:
    /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-evegwvxyndhicigkgkdhjdmnybwq/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDataScanner.o
    /Users/user/Desktop/myapp/MobFox.framework/MobFox(MobFox)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_CJSONDeserializer in:
    /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-evegwvxyndhicigkgkdhjdmnybwq/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CJSONDeserializer.o
    /Users/user/Desktop/myapp/MobFox.framework/MobFox(MobFox)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_CJSONScanner in:
    /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-evegwvxyndhicigkgkdhjdmnybwq/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CJSONScanner.o
    /Users/user/Desktop/myapp/MobFox.framework/MobFox(MobFox)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_CJSONSerializer in:
    /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-evegwvxyndhicigkgkdhjdmnybwq/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CJSONSerializer.o
    /Users/user/Desktop/myapp/MobFox.framework/MobFox(MobFox)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CDataScanner.current in:
    /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-evegwvxyndhicigkgkdhjdmnybwq/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDataScanner.o
    /Users/user/Desktop/myapp/MobFox.framework/MobFox(MobFox)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CDataScanner.data in:
    /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-evegwvxyndhicigkgkdhjdmnybwq/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDataScanner.o
    /Users/user/Desktop/myapp/MobFox.framework/MobFox(MobFox)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CDataScanner.end in:
    /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-evegwvxyndhicigkgkdhjdmnybwq/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDataScanner.o
    /Users/user/Desktop/myapp/MobFox.framework/MobFox(MobFox)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CDataScanner.length in:
    /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-evegwvxyndhicigkgkdhjdmnybwq/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDataScanner.o
    /Users/user/Desktop/myapp/MobFox.framework/MobFox(MobFox)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CDataScanner.start in:
    /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-evegwvxyndhicigkgkdhjdmnybwq/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDataScanner.o
    /Users/user/Desktop/myapp/MobFox.framework/MobFox(MobFox)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CJSONDeserializer.scanner in:
    /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-evegwvxyndhicigkgkdhjdmnybwq/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CJSONDeserializer.o
    /Users/user/Desktop/myapp/MobFox.framework/MobFox(MobFox)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CJSONScanner.nullObject in:
    /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-evegwvxyndhicigkgkdhjdmnybwq/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CJSONScanner.o
    /Users/user/Desktop/myapp/MobFox.framework/MobFox(MobFox)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CJSONScanner.strictEscapeCodes in:
    /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-evegwvxyndhicigkgkdhjdmnybwq/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CJSONScanner.o
    /Users/user/Desktop/myapp/MobFox.framework/MobFox(MobFox)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDataScanner in:
    /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-evegwvxyndhicigkgkdhjdmnybwq/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDataScanner.o
    /Users/user/Desktop/myapp/MobFox.framework/MobFox(MobFox)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CJSONDeserializer in:
    /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-evegwvxyndhicigkgkdhjdmnybwq/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CJSONDeserializer.o
    /Users/user/Desktop/myapp/MobFox.framework/MobFox(MobFox)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CJSONScanner in:
    /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-evegwvxyndhicigkgkdhjdmnybwq/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CJSONScanner.o
    /Users/user/Desktop/myapp/MobFox.framework/MobFox(MobFox)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CJSONSerializer in:
    /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-evegwvxyndhicigkgkdhjdmnybwq/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CJSONSerializer.o
    /Users/user/Desktop/myapp/MobFox.framework/MobFox(MobFox)
duplicate symbol _kJSONDeserializerErrorDomain in:
    /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-evegwvxyndhicigkgkdhjdmnybwq/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CJSONDeserializer.o
    /Users/user/Desktop/myapp/MobFox.framework/MobFox(MobFox)
duplicate symbol _kJSONScannerErrorDomain in:
    /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-evegwvxyndhicigkgkdhjdmnybwq/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CJSONScanner.o
    /Users/user/Desktop/myapp/MobFox.framework/MobFox(MobFox)
```

Any idea why it happen? i think it is because both my app and mobfox use this json framework.
it's possible to disable their code?

Comment: Looks like you are compiling objects from `MobFox` **and** linking to the `MobFox` framework (or linking both the static library and linking to the `MobFox` framework).

Comment: Seems like external library and your project using same json Serialization classes, that's why compiler compiles it twice.

Comment: it's possible to disable compile it in the external library?

Comment: MTA did you find answer for this?

Comment: @venky `MobFox` are using `CJSONDeserializer`.What i did in my project was deleting the `CJSONDeserializer` and replace it with the native JSON parser